# enter command -$ npm install -g hexo-cli

Tags: node.js, hexo

I have a question ah..   It began like this~

when I press the Command - $ 'npm install -g hexo-cli',The error follows.

```
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules/usr/local/lib

npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, access        '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'
npm ERR!     at Error (native)
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES: permission denied, access    '/usr/local/lib/node_modules']
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'access',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
```

Comment: Please add sudo in front of the command.

Comment: Who is owner and what is the mod of /usr/local/lib ?

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```sh
$ sudo npm install -g hexo-cli
```

[Here](https://docs.npmjs.com/downloading-and-installing-packages-globally) and [here](https://docs.npmjs.com/resolving-eacces-permissions-errors-when-installing-packages-globally) you have the exact information about that error.